# Is it possible to achieve this type of filtering with Cypher

Tags: cypher, redisgraph

I have a DSL to query RedisGraph which looks like this:

```
App::Graph.query(movie: { title: 'Matrix' }, country: { value: 'Italy' , value: 'Spain', value: 'Greece' })
```

Which produces this cypher query:

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Actor)
WHERE m.title = 'Matrix'
WITH m, collect(a) as actors
WHERE 1 = 1
AND (movie)<-[:AVAILABLE_IN]-(:Country {value: 'Italy'})
AND (movie)<-[:AVAILABLE_IN]-(:Country {value: 'Spain'})
AND (movie)<-[:AVAILABLE_IN]-(:Country {value: 'Greece'})
RETURN actors, m
```

Question: in some cases a `Country` node, for example Spain, will have no `edges`, and as such currently the above cypher query would rightly return no results. But is it possible to rewrite the query above so that it would ignore the `Country` node if it has no edges, matching and returning nodes that are connected to the remaining initially defined list of countries i.e. Italy, Greece?

I've tried many option, below being the last one, but have not found a way to achieve this

```
MATCH (m:Movie)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Actor)
WHERE m.title = 'Matrix'
WITH m, collect(a) as actors
MATCH (m)<-[:AVAILABLE_IN]-(connected_countries)
WHERE connected_countries.value IN ['Italy', 'Spain', 'Greece']
WITH m, actors, collect(connected_countries.value) as relevant_countries
WHERE 1 = 1
AND ((movie)<-[:AVAILABLE_IN]-(:Country {value: 'Italy'}) AND IN relevant_countries)
AND ((movie)<-[:AVAILABLE_IN]-(:Country {value: 'Spain'}) AND IN relevant_countries)
AND ((movie)<-[:AVAILABLE_IN]-(:Country {value: 'Greece'}) AND IN relevant_countries)
RETURN actors, m
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
MATCH (m:Movie {title:'Matrix'})
WITH m AS m
UNWIND ['Italy', 'Spain', 'Greece'] AS country_name
MATCH (:Country {value: country_name})-[:AVAILABLE_IN]->(m)<-[:ACTED_IN]-(a:Actor)
WITH m, collect(a) as actors
RETURN actors, m
```

Comment: Hey @SWilly22 thanks for getting back, when using your query I get extra results back as a match is being done on each country, one at a time, rather than all of them, and maybe I phrased the question wrong, but essentially I expect only movies that have edges to all of the countries to be returned. To add, I've achieved the ability to do that since posting this question, and did so by counting the number of edges, however have now run into an issue where some of my queries need to handle (( AND) OR ) cases as well as ((AND) AND). Is there a timeline for pattern comprehension to be supported?